# NET Core - DI at Biz logic layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have 4 levels in my project - webapi(UI), biz logic, DAL and DBContext.

in context file, using AddDBContext, i added DBContext and using ADDScoped i added biz logic object.  so in controller's constructor, autoatically i was able to get instance of bizlogic object. and in bizlogics's constructor, i was able to get the instance of DBContext.

but what i want to achieve is to create instance of DAL in bizlogic layer using DI.  I tried using AddScoped in startup.cs, but it is not working.  below are the code

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<ClientEntities>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


        // Repositories
        //services.AddScoped<IDBClient, DBClient>(); -- my DAL layer
        services.AddScoped<ITAConfigRepository, TAConfigRepository>(); -- my biz logic layer

        //var dbContext = DBContextFactory.Create("DB1");
        //services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<dbContext>(); -- my DbContext layer

    }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
 public TAMController(ITAConfigRepository repo)
    {
        _itaconfigrepository = repo;
    }
```

**bizlogic layer**

```
public TAConfigRepository(ClientEntities context)  -- This works
    {
        ctx = context;
    }

public TAConfigRepository(IDBClient obj)  -- This does not work
    {
        _dbclient = obj;
    }
```

**DAL layer**

```
 public DBClient(ClientEntities ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }
```

**DBContextlayer**

```
 public ClientEntities(DbContextOptions<ClientEntities> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
```

how do i achieve this?  some ppl may be suggest to use DAL layer, but the issue remains same if i want to create instance of any other biz logic class inside this biz logic class.

Also, if there is any error, am getting only 500 error.  am not seeing the actual error.  how do i see the actual error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't register `IDBClient` in startup, you can't use it. Simple as that. So just register it

Comment: i tried it, it still didn't work.  it just shows 500 error.  it does not even hit the controller. how do i see the error?

Comment: if i understand correctly, if we register in startup.cs file, we can inject it in any controller, even if that class is in different project. is that correct?

Comment: Every dependency must be registered. Dependencies that are not registered, can't be injected. It do not matter in which library the class is, which is being resolved. The only thing important is, that it's resolved from DI and it's not limited to the controller, but since the controller is the entry point of every request, ASP.NET Core implicitly resolve a controllers parameters which in turn resolves the dependencies of that services (i.e. Controller may resolve IUserRepository and UserRepository may have ApplicationDbContext as dependency)

Comment: @Tseng am getting this error  System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 
'Visa.IntelliLink.Data.Repositories.TAConfigRepository' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.  when i use this constructor TAConfigRepository(DBClient dbClient)
        {
            _dbClient = dbClient;
        }

Comment: @poke can you take a look at this? thanks.

Comment: `TAConfigRepository(DBClient dbClient) { _dbClient = dbClient; }` << When you register it as interface, you must also inject the interface, i.e. when you register it as `services.AddScoped<IDBClient, DBClient>();` you also have to inject `IDBClient`. It should have one single constructor or at least one which fulfills all the dependencies, so if you have two constructors with `IDBClient` and `ClientEntities`, then it won't work since DI doesn't know which one of them to use. By default the DI tries to use the constructor with the most parameters

Comment: @Tseng Thanks TSeng.  my repo class has only one constructor which takes dbclient as param. my dbclient has only one constructor which takes ClientEntities as param.  so are you saying this setup won't work?

Comment: No, that's not what I said. It should work, but you have somewhere an error or missing registration, i.e. `services.AddScoped<DBClient>()` or `services.AddScoped<DBClient, DBClient>()` instead of `services.AddScoped<IDBClient, DBClient>()`

Comment: TSeng, tried it, didnt work.  any change i can mail you the code, so you can take a look? thanks.

Comment: @TSeng - can i mail you my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TSeng's last comment worked and for some reason, the construtor was private in my code.  after changing it to public, it started to work.